# Why does OOM killer output not appear in dmesg?

Tags: raspbian, linux, raspbian-buster, memory

I've got a Buster box (10.2) and I'm investigating some system freezes. While going through that, I think I'm not getting the OOM output in the syslog. For instance, running
`tail /dev/zero` which is [known](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188024/how-to-test-oom-killer-from-command-line) to trigger it, the only output I get is in the SSH shell:

> `tail: memory exhausted`

(zsh). But **nothing** is mentioned in the dmesg (or journalctl fwiw) outputs, whereas on my Arch box the very same command does indeed result in a dmesg line. Why is that? Is perhaps some setting missing?

Comment: I do not understand your question. You presume to much details you do not explain.

Comment: Dear @Ingo, the question is no bigger deal than it looks: simply when the OOM runs, there _should_ be an output message in the syslog. On my raspbian box, I'm not getting one (are you?) - why is that?